# PHP regex code for "does not match once"

Tags: javascript, php

Working on code similar to [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481849/php-and-javascript-email-validation-of-symbol) but for passwords ($email is now $password). Trying have validation check to see if password field has at least one number, one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, and one of the symbols !@#$%^&*

PHP-side validation uses regex

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*]{6,20}$/
```

which works fine. However for js validation I'm using this for "if password does not contain one of each"

```
if (preg_match('/([^a-z]{1})([^A-Z]{1})(^\d{1})([^!@#$%^&*]{1})+/', $password, $matches)) {
echo 'Password must contain _, _, _';
```

Total beginner and very confused.

Comment: The simplest thing to do is just toss this. It doesn't improve password security, is annoying to users and incomprehensible gibberish to anyone trying to maintain this code later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the same regex pattern in js too??

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*]{6,20}$/
```

This would work fine in js as well. If only you need to see `if password does not contain one of each` use a negation as

```
if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*]{6,20}$/', $password, $matches)) {
echo 'Password must contain _, _, _';
```

Comment: was testing out code and did this while waiting. Set as if true do nothing and else show the echo and works perfectly

Comment: You could replace the quantifier `{6,20}` by a `+` if you need to do the length check separately (this being a character validation only as per the message).