# PHP and Javascript Validation of Password Match

Tags: javascript, php

Trying to get page to dynamically show if passwords match (echo 'Match' or 'Do not match'). (Similiar to previous question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481849/php-and-javascript-email-validation-of-symbol).)

Looking to check if password1 and password2 are the same as you type in either the 'password' or 'confirm password' input boxes.

**EDIT:** Seems elseif ($password2 == $password1) isn't checking for the match as I intended. Posting of password1 and password2 works (#feedback changes to 'Do not match' as you type in either input box, but 'Match' never shows). Any help on how to fix this code is appreciated.

check.php

```
<?php
include __DIR__ . '/mysqli_connect.php';

$password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['password2']);
$password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['password1']);

if ($password2==NULL && $password1==NULL) {
    echo '';
} elseif ($password2 == $password1) {
    echo 'Match';
} else {
    echo 'Do not match';
}
```

register.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#feedback').load('/includes/check.php').show();

    $('#password1').keyup(function() {
        $.post('/includes/check.php', { password1: form.password1.value }, 
        function(result) {
            $('#feedback').html(result).show;
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#feedback').load('/includes/check.php').show();

    $('#password2').keyup(function() {
        $.post('/includes/check.php', { password2: form.password2.value }, 
        function(result) {
            $('#feedback').html(result).show;
        });
    });
});
</script>

<form action="register.php" method="post" name="form">

<input id="password1" class="signup_input_box" type="password" name="password1" maxlength="20" value="<?php if (isset($trimmed['password1'])) echo $trimmed['password1']; ?>">

<input id="password2" class="signup_input_box" type="password" name="password2" maxlength="20" value="<?php if (isset($trimmed['password2'])) echo $trimmed['password2']; ?>">
<div id="feedback"></div>

<p><center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></center>
</form>
```

Comment: And your problem/question is?

Comment: Sorry, the code isn't working. Looking for any help as to what I did wrong.

Comment: Which code isn't working?

Comment: can you describe your problem with your code? Or can you write down your error code?

Comment: the 'elseif ($password2 == $password1)'. When I type the same pw into both input boxes, 'Match' doesn't show, only the 'Do not match' echo does.

Comment: to compare your pw dont use this function before:
`$password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['password2']);
$password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['password1']);`
that make a resource from your string. and this didnt compareble !

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skipped using MySql posting and used JS only to check the value of the password inputs and show text upon keyup. [Reference here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717588/checking-password-match-while-typing)